# Facing error while upgrading to angular 8 from angular 7 facing CSS,SCSS errors

Tags: css, sass, angular8

**I want to upgarde angular 7 to angular 8 
When serve application facing issue in terminal**

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

    @include transition(opacity .2s);
         ^
      Mixin transition is missing argument $type.
      in /home/webelight-pc/www/thunder-school/src/assets/sass/scss/core/_horizontal-timeline.scss (line 12, column 11)
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css ./src/assets/css/prism.min.css ./node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css ./node_modules/ngx-ui-switch/ui-switch.component.css ./src/assets/css/wizard.css ./src/assets/css/quill.snow.css ./src/assets/css/quill.bubble.css ./src/assets/css/hopscotch.css ./node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/scss/angular-calendar.scss ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/material.css ./node_modules/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/themes/default.theme.css ./src/assets/css/demo.css ./src/assets/sass/app.scss ./node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/webelight-pc/www/thunder-school/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css' in '/home/webelight-pc/www/thunder-school'
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css ./src/assets/css/prism.min.css ./node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css ./node_modules/ngx-ui-switch/ui-switch.component.css ./src/assets/css/wizard.css ./src/assets/css/quill.snow.css ./src/assets/css/quill.bubble.css ./src/assets/css/hopscotch.css ./node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/scss/angular-calendar.scss ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/material.css ./node_modules/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/themes/default.theme.css ./src/assets/css/demo.css ./src/assets/sass/app.scss ./node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/webelight-pc/www/thunder-school/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css' in '/home/webelight-pc/www/thunder-school'
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css ./src/assets/css/prism.min.css ./node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css ./node_modules/ngx-ui-switch/ui-switch.component.css ./src/assets/css/wizard.css ./src/assets/css/quill.snow.css ./src/assets/css/quill.bubble.css ./src/assets/css/hopscotch.css ./node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/scss/angular-calendar.scss ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/material.css ./node_modules/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/themes/default.theme.css ./src/assets/css/demo.css ./src/assets/sass/app.scss ./node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/webelight-pc/www/thunder-school/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/material.css' in '/home/webelight-pc/www/thunder-school'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-quill/fesm2015/ngx-quill.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'quill' in '/home/webelight-pc/www/thunder-school/node_modules/ngx-quill/fesm2015'
```

Comment: put a comma after opacity

Answer (score 0):

The transition function have two parameters

@include transition(cssProperty, animationDuration transitionFunction);

the transition function is not mandatory it's ease by default

in your case it could be something like

```
@include transition(opacity, 2s);
```

or

```
@include transition(opacity, 2s ease-in);
```

the complete list of transition function is :

- ease
- linear
- ease-in
- ease-out
- ease-in-out
- step-start
- step-end
- steps(int,start|end)
- cubic-bezier(n,n,n,n)

more sample can be found : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp

Answer (score 0):

@include transition(opacity, .2s ease-out);